# How to play audio only from video file on Android?

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have mp4 and wmv movie files and need to play only sound not video screen. How to do it?? Could I get sound track from movie file??

I know if I hide the SurfaceView from screen, I can only hear sound.. but I have tried a lot but.. it is impossible.

If you have any solution to extract sound track from movie file, please let me know..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the mediaplayer API in your app then don't call the API `public void setDisplay (SurfaceHolder sh)`. This will ensure that only the audio is played out even if the video content is present..

More info in android doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDisplay%28android.view.SurfaceHolder%29)

Answer (score 2):

Use following code, Optimize following code as per your requirement. It play video from youtube.

```
try {
            final MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        m.setDataSource("rtsp://v8.cache3.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwlQP1m32SiSYxMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3JlbGF0ZWRggqG7w9aS2-1MDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp");
                        m.prepare();
                        m.start();  
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            t.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```