# How to play just sound from mp4 file in android?

Tags: android, audio, mp4, live-wallpaper

Can we play just audio from mp4 file ?
I don't want to view video so that i can play mp4 file in background in live wallpaper .

I tried to play mp4 file by using MediaPlayer but sound is not playing .
Any hint ?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate one, check here, with the proposed answer fits your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056034/how-to-play-audio-only-from-video-file-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link it shows something ..

(1). [Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App)

(2).   [play-foreground-and-background-music](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/11/play-foreground-and-background-music.html)

and to play audio with video you can go for this ..

(3).  [how-play-video-and-audio-android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android)

Comment: @Thanks... I am checking links you gave me